# Failed read content from json using cUrl in PHP

Tags: php, json, curl

This is my first time using web service. My PHP server get the json data from .net server where it is encoded to base64.

The problem now is, i failed to read each attribute inside the data:

```
Array ( [JSONDataResult] => {"file":"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","fileSize":"8484","returnCode":"0"} )
```

There are 3 columns:

1. file
2. fileSize
3. returnCode

I have tried to get data using Object, Array or json but always failed.

```
//$json = json_decode($data, true); //array
//$json = json_decode($data); //object
//echo $result; //JSONDataResult
```

Below is one of the FAILED method. The full process coding:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {
        $project_code = $_GET['project_code'];

        $url = "http://1.2.3.4/to/file/process";
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, curlopt_httpheader, array ("Content-type:application/json"));

        $result = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        $data = file_get_contents($url);

        $json = json_decode($data, true); //array
        //$json = json_decode($data); //object
        //echo $result; //JSONDataResult
        //print_r($json);

        foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
            if (!is_array($value)) {
                //always goes here
                echo "not array: ".$key . '=>' . $value . '<br/>';
            } else {
                foreach ($value as $key => $val) {
                    echo "is array: ".$key . '=>' . $val . '<br/>';
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Guys help me to read the content. I do not mind using which method as long as i can read each column inside the content. Many-many thank you.

[jangankecamsaya]

Comment: what is output or error?

Comment: The `foreach` looks like blind search to me. A call to `print_r($json);` right after `json_decode($data, true);` should be enough to point you in the right direction.

Comment: @Vasim Vanzara not array: JSONDataResult=>{"file":"iVBORw0KGgo..bla...blaaa..long base64 text so i removed","fileSize":"8484","returnCode":"0"}

Comment: Your array as shown contains one element only - the key is `JSONDataResult`, and it has a _string_ value. You need to decode that string value as JSON, before you can access individual “elements” inside it.

Comment: @axiac The result is was as above under "The problem now is, i failed to read each attribute inside the data:"

Comment: @Daniel can you share an example URL so I/we can test it too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the data you posted in the question is the output of `print_r($json);`, it is clear that `$json` is an array that contains only one value (the big JSON) associated to the key `JSONDataResult`. It basically looks like this:

```
$json = array('JSONDataResult' => '{"file":"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","fileSize":"8484","returnCode":"0"}');
```

A call to `json_decode($json['JSONDataResult'], TRUE)` decodes the big string into an array like this:

```
array(
    'file' => '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',
    'fileSize' => 8484,
    'returnCode' => 0,
);
```

The value of `file` is encoded using base64. The complete code should look like this:

```
// Decode the JSON
$fileInfo = json_decode($json, TRUE);
// Decode the file content
$content = base64_decode($fileInfo['file']);
// Visually inspect its the decoded file content
print_r($content);      // Congratulations, it's a PNG!

// Put the content in a file
file_put_contents('...the file path here...', $content);
// Use getimagesize() to learn about the image type
// an rename the file using the correct termination.
```

Btw, the value of `fileSize` is the length of the `file` field, i.e. the content encoded using base64, not the length of the actual PNG file on disk (as I would expect).

Answer (score 0):

You tried to

```
$json = json_decode($data[0], true); //array
```

???
(mind the access on the first field on $data)